# How to resolve the javax.script.ScriptException?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using Java 1.7 (project requirement) . I'm executing this code on a Horton cluster for one of my Apache Spark project. Should I include any special jars?

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: syntax error (<Unknown Source>#1)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.compile(RhinoScriptEngine.java:392)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.compile(RhinoScriptEngine.java:374)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that there is a syntax error in the javascript that you are trying to execute (using Rhino).

You need to figure out what it is.  Start by eye-balling the code.  If that doesn't help, then download a Javascript checker or pick an online Javascript validator.

> Should I include any special jars ?

There is no indication that you are missing any JAR files.